# Headset microphone not working and not detected on ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, asus, microphone

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on an Asus n551vw laptop, but when I connect the headset, its microphone is not recognized (but its sound works).
[Sound setting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUC4Q.png)
After a lot of searching, if I add the code `options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi` to the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, microphone it will be detected after restarting, but does not work.
[Sound setting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLCLG.png)
After the laptop is completely turned off, if I boot to Windows first and then to Ubuntu, the microphone will work and no problem, but because of this I have to install Windows as a dual boot and do these things every time.
What is the solution to this problem?
[Codec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqIVB.png)

Comment: Do you know if that headset is supported by Ubuntu?

Comment: @David Hi, I tried several different headsets but they all had the same problem.